# How to reverse String.fromCharCode?

Tags: javascript, char, reverse

String.fromCharCode(72) gives H. How to get number 72 from char H?

Comment: the code in the question is what I came here for, not the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
'H'.charCodeAt(0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Will it work only with english words? when I tried to find the char code for a tamil word its not working properly. 

If I use String.fromCharCode(2974); it returns the character 'ஞ', the same way, If I use 'ஞ'.charCodeAt(0) am getting 38, and that is for '&', why is it so?

Comment: @shanish: What do you get if you write `String.fromCharCode(2974).charCodeAt(0)`? (It works for me.) Perhaps your editor and/or source file are not Unicode-friendly.

Answer (score 10):

Use charCodeAt:

```
var str = 'H';
var charcode = str.charCodeAt(0);
```

Answer (score 8):

@Silvio's answer is only true for code points up to 0xFFFF (which in the end is the maximum that String.fromCharCode can output). You can't always assume the length of a character is one:

```
''.length
-> 2
```

Here's something that works:

```
var utf16ToDig = function(s) {
    var length = s.length;
    var index = -1;
    var result = "";
    var hex;
    while (++index < length) {
        hex = s.charCodeAt(index).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        result += ('0000' + hex).slice(-4);
    }
    return parseInt(result, 16);
}
```

Using it:

```
utf16ToDig('').toString(16)
-> "d800df30"
```

(Inspiration from https://mothereff.in/utf-8)

Answer (score 6):

**You can define your own global functions like this:**

```
function CHR(ord)
{
    return String.fromCharCode(ord);
}

function ORD(chr)
{
    return chr.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

**Then use them like this:**

```
var mySTR = CHR(72);
```

or

```
var myNUM = ORD('H');
```

(If you want to use them more than once, and/or a lot in your code.)

Comment: Please do **not** use my suggestion any more. I strongly suggest using an _object_ to wrap your functions, instead of definging them globally.

Answer (score 1):

`String.fromCharCode` accepts multiple arguments, so this is valid:

```
const binaryArray = [10, 24] // ...
str = String.fromCharCode(...binaryArray)
```

---

In case you're looking for the *opposite of that* (like I was), this might come in handy:

```
const binaryArray = str
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, next) =>
    [...acc, next.charCodeAt(0)],
    []
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to consider encoding, note that the `charCodeAt` method from `String` object will default to the utf16 encoding. You can use the `string_decoder` object and the encoding parameter of the [*Node.js* `Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object to apply a specific encoding.

The `charCodeAt` method provides only ascii/utf-16 encoding even with utf-8 encoded `String` object :

```js
str=new String(new Buffer([195,169]))
// -> [String: 'é']
str.charCodeAt(0)
// -> 233
```

Building the string with `fromCharCode` would not be right as it expects **UTF-16** :

```js
myStr=String.fromCharCode(50089, 65, 233)
// -> '쎩Aé'
Buffer.from(myStr, 'utf-8')
// -> <Buffer ec 8e a9 41 c3 a9>
Buffer.from(myStr, 'ascii')
// -> <Buffer a9 41 e9>
myStr.charCodeAt(0)
// -> 50089
myStr.charCodeAt(2)
// -> 233
```

Here is a simple example to encode and decode UTF8 bytes and ASCII bytes :

```js
var dec=new string_decoder.StringDecoder('utf-8');
dec.write(Buffer.from([65,67,195,169,98]));
// -> 'ACéb'
var theBytes=new Buffer('aéé','utf-8'); 
// -> <Buffer 61 c3 a9 c3 a9>
```

```js
var dec=new string_decoder.StringDecoder('ascii')
dec.write(Buffer.from([65,67,195,169,98]))
// -> 'ACC)b'
var theBytes=new Buffer('aéé','ascii')
// -> <Buffer 61 e9 e9>
```

The `StringDecoder.write` method will return you a `String` object from the provided bytes buffer.

The encoding parameter of the `Buffer` object gives you a way to get a `Buffer` object feed with the encoded bytes from a provided String.

So to get the ASCII encoding of char 'H' :

```js
new Buffer('H','ascii');
// -> <Buffer 48>
new Buffer('H','ascii')[0];
// -> 72
```

That way, you could also handle multi bytes encoded chars like that:

```js
new Buffer('é','ascii');
// -> <Buffer e9>
arr=new Buffer('é','ascii');
// -> <Buffer e9>
code=arr.readUIntBE(0,arr.length);
// -> 233
code.toString(16);
// -> 'e9'
```

```js
new Buffer('é','utf-8');
// -> <Buffer c3 a9>
arr=new Buffer('é','utf-8');
// -> <Buffer c3 a9>
code=arr.readUIntBE(0,arr.length);
// -> 50089
code.toString(16)
// -> 'c3a9'
```