# How to show a string as its unicode code points?

Tags: javascript

Just from a browser developer console or Node.js repl, what's an easy way to transcribe a string as its unicode representation? For example I can input `'\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F'`  and the repl will show me `'Hello'`

```
> '\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F'
"Hello"
```

How can I reverse this?

```
> something('Hello')
"\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F"
```

For example. I hope there are some convenient built-ins or browser console/repl support.

Comment: I not sure it is possible. In JS `"\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F" === "Hello" // true` so they're equivalent. --- Unless the backslashes are escaped, maybe?

Comment: Would this solve your issue [How to reverse String.fromCharCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071602/how-to-reverse-string-fromcharcode)

Comment: @Ant I think this question is the opposite of that one.